# How to send data using GET to Java Script

Tags: javascript, get

I wan't to know How to send data using GET to Java Script
like from

link: C:/folder/test.html?x=1

```
<script>
//when page accessed
//access x data sent in from the link
</script>
```

Note, this is for client page not server!

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse `location.search`. A simple implementation would be:

```
var matches = null;
var params = {}, raw_params = location.search.substring(1).split('&');
for (i in raw_params)
{
    matches = raw_params[i].match (/^([^=]+)=(.+)$/);
    if (matches) params[matches[1]] = matches[2];
}
```